# How to programmatically download an HTML page in Android and get its HTML?

Tags: android, html, android-emulator, download

I need to download an HTML page programmatically and then get its HTML. I am mainly concerned with the downloading of the page. If I download the page, where will I put it?

Will I have to keep in an String variable? If yes then how?

Comment: Here is my answer from duplicate question. 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14343789/1237023

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the html-source of a page from a html link in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423498/how-to-get-the-html-source-of-a-page-from-a-html-link-in-android)

Answer (score 8):

[This site](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device) provides a good explanation on how to download a file, and also how to set the location to where it should be stored. You do not have to, and should not, keep it in a string variable. If you are to manipulate the data I would suggest you use an [XML parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

**You can call this method in doInBackground of AsyncTask**

```
String html = "";
String url = "ENTER URL TO DOWNLOAD";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    str.append(line);
}
in.close();
html = str.toString();
```