# Android - Searching and navigating the web

Tags: android

I was wondering if it was at all possible to attempt the following in an Android app:
I want the user to be able to enter a few keywords, then in the background (while showing a loading animation) have the app search google for the entered keywords, navigate to the first search result, then search the resulting web page for a URL leading to a particular domain, and return this URL to a list in the app?
Is this possible, and could anyone nudge me in the right direction to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google search](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html) api by Http request methods in backend while showing loading animation, which provides its search results details...

But also look out for restrictions in using this api, i guess in terms of max search requests/day..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This should start me off with google searches. The rest of my problem could probably be solved by retrieving and parsing the HTML source code of the resulting page (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423498/how-to-get-the-html-source-of-a-page-from-a-html-link-in-android)).

Comment: The search api would provide you direct Json format results, which you can directly parse to ..