# How to show text from a website?

Tags: java, android, show

I am trying to capture the text of a page and then display it in my application.
  But when I run the program does not display the text.
The site is  http://www.bovalpo.com/cgi-local/xml_bcv.pl?URL=1

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_examplebackground);

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.bovalpo.com/cgi-local/xml_bcv.pl?URL=1"); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String inputLine="";
        String inputText = ""; 
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            inputText = inputText + inputLine;
        }

        System.out.println(inputText);
    }catch(MalformedURLException t){
        System.out.println("error de url");
    } catch(Throwable t){
        System.out.println("error de bufffer");
    }
}
```

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423498/how-to-get-the-html-source-of-a-page-from-a-html-link-in-android

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: any error, I have Internet permits and all! :/

Comment: Have you verified that the inputstream actually opened before you read it?

Comment: only need show "abierto" in the app, captured from this site

Comment: You should not be doing any web requests on the main ui thread. Do it on a separate thread or use async task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You the formats of text are different. You need to encode both of them in `UTF` format.

Encode it something like:

`String data = URLEncoder.encode("data", "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `readLine` if `InputStream` does not provides new line character, or, it will be blocked (waiting for new line character) there.

I suggest use [apache-commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) library to read text from `InputStream`

```
String charset = "UTF-8";
inputText = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString (url, charset);
```

Comment: im used httpURLConnection, InputStream  BufferedReader :)