# overriding javascript function in a webview

Tags: android

I want to integrate an existing website into my webview but also override a javascript function that exists on this website with my own version? Then I can use the java-javascript bridge.  I have tried using the following but it seems to execute the function only

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    webView.loadUrl("javascript: (function myFunc() { "
        + "alert('overriden alert ha!');"
        + "})()");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

1. [grab html page source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423498/how-to-get-the-html-source-of-a-page-from-a-html-link-in-android)
2. Edit it. (add into html source you grabbed, easy way : `replace("<head>","<head>"+"your code");`
3. load edited String of HTML using `webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", string, "text/html", "utf-8", "");`

Comment: i would do this all in onPageFinished?