# Override current Javascript functions with Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, interface, webview

I'm porting my website to Android, and using an Webview to show the content to user. There are a lot of Javascript functions in my website, and I want to intercept them. I already seen [a "solution" here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557872/overriding-javascript-function-in-a-webview).

However, I think there should be a more proper way, using Javascript Interface:

```
this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(this.webJavascriptInterface, "Android");
```

This way, I have to modify my website to call both `myFunction()` and `Android.myFunction()`. I tried to leave a blank String in the interface:

```
this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(this.webJavascriptInterface, "");
```

but the result was as I guess, it couldn't work. Is there a way to override current Javascript functions in Webview?

Answer (score 3):

```
// android
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:function inputClick(val){native.abcd(val);}");     // override js function
    }
});

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");

webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void abcd(int val) {
        Log.e(TAG, "#js abcd" + val);
    }
}, "native");

<!-- html -->
<input type="button" onclick="inputClick(2)" value="button">
```

== add some explain at Sep 07,2015

because javascript function could be **override**, so you can **override javascript function** while page finished.

if not, normal implement maybe like this:

```
// js code
function inputClick(val) {
    native.abcd(val); // native and abcd defined in WebView method addJavascriptInterface
}
```

but this normal implement is seems not work in iOS(Object-C), and must edit HTML page.
is just move the java-javascript bridge code from HTML to Java. (see method **onPageFinished** in example code)

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by injecting a new javascript that redefines old function, basically you can override existing function with this.

For example, to override `window.print()` function, I use this

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.print = function() {Android.printPage();}")
```