# How to force HttpClient to get plain html ?

Tags: android, httpclient

I am writing simple Android application which parse html at specific positions, take some data and show in a `ListView`. As app need only plain html response is there any possibility to request only plain html. How to exclude css and java script files, images and similar from http request?
I am using apache `HttpClient` object.

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question? If so, remember to perform this on a separate thread to avoid UI blocking (probably want to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html))

(From [How to get the html-source of a page from a html link in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423498/how-to-get-the-html-source-of-a-page-from-a-html-link-in-android))

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

String html = "";
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    str.append(line);
}
in.close();
html = str.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already have implemented that (similar code). 
But I am wondering does it takes only plain html response or everything (images, css files, java script files and similar) for that particular http request. If yes, how can I explicitly disable everything except plain html response...