# Get HTML code from url in android

Tags: android

I was wondering if is any way to get HTML code from any url and save that code as String in code? 
I have a method:

```
private String getHtmlData(Context context, String data){
    String head = "<head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'verdana';src: url('file://"+ context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/verdana.ttf');}body {font-family: 'verdana';}</style></head>";
    String htmlData= "<html>"+head+"<body>"+data+"</body></html>" ;
    return htmlData;
 }
```

and I want to get this "data" from url. How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (wrote it from the hand)

```
URL google = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(google.openStream()));
String input;
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
while ((input = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    stringBuffer.append(input);
}
in.close();
String htmlData = stringBuffer.toString();
```

Comment: I get 06-10 10:43:45.094: E/AndroidRuntime(7210): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fontfordroid/com.example.fontfordroid.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: did you give your app internet permission?

Comment: its strange, I just tested it by myself and it works fine! Else take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423498/how-to-get-the-html-source-of-a-page-from-a-html-link-in-android

Comment: You paste this code in Thread or AsyncTask? I paste this code in onCreate.

Comment: From API LEVEL 11, you cannot perform network related task on main thread, you have to do it in another thread. Otherwise you will get an  exception "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException".

Comment: I'm using it in AsyncTask. Perform all the network related task in separate thread. Your problem should get solved.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. That's actually the response body. You can get it like this:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
String htmlPage = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "ISO-8859-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188049/parse-html-in-android) please, any other parser will work too, or you can even make your own checking the strings and retrieving just the part you want.