# How to get source code from getBrowserForDocument()

Tags: javascript, android, gecko, geckofx, geckodriver

I am developing customized gecko browser. How to get source code of visited page from the given below code.

```
function onPageLoad(event) {

  let contentDocument = event.target;

  let browser = BrowserApp.getBrowserForDocument(contentDocument);
  console.log("Page loaded: " + browser.contentTitle);

}
```

This is mozilla gecko browser code.
I am getting the output of browser.contentTitle for webpage title. But i want to know how to get full html code.
what is the code for getting the source code from getBrowserForDocument();

Comment: are you tried document.body.innerHTML

Comment: I want to get the source code of current running page.

Comment: Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680562/can-javascript-read-the-source-of-any-web-page

Comment: I think it is not possible. I am developing gecko browser. i want to redesign the view web pages where visited in my browser. The source code is https://github.com/ncalexan/geckobrowser-gradle

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423498/how-to-get-the-html-source-of-a-page-from-a-html-link-in-android